# Evaluation and plot the result of NIntegrate obtained from NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration

First I solved coupled ODE using NDSolve. Now I want to integrate the expression `(p'''[0] - ((1.0/k)*p''[0]) + (beta*m*m*s[0])` with respect to the parameter `x` over the interval `[0,1]`. I need a plot of the integrated expression, say `pr` as a function of the parameter `F`. I am trying with the following codes.

```
a = 0.5;
b = 2.0;
t = 0.0;
Q0 = 1.0;
alp = 0.5;
alpha = 0.5;
beta=1.0;
k = 0.5;
m = 10.0;
h = 1.0 - (a*Cos[Pi*(x - t)]*Cos[Pi*(x - t)]);
eq1 = {s''[y] == (m/alpha)*Sinh[alpha*s[y]]};
bc1 = {s'[0] == 0, s[h] == 1};
eq2 = {p''''[y] - (1/k)*p''[y] + beta*m*m*s'[y] == 0};
bc2 = {p[0] == 0, p''[0] == 0, p[h] == F, p'[h] == 0};
px = ParametricNDSolve[
   Join[eq1, eq2, bc1, bc2], {s, p}, {y, 0, h}, {x, F} ];
pr = Evaluate[
  NIntegrate[(p'''[y] - ((1.0/k)*p''[y]) + (beta*m*m*s[y])), {x, 0, 
     1}] /. {y -> 0}]
```

The graph of Integrated value vs F should look like the following graph. Kindly note that here `beta1` is another parameter involved in the problem. But for simplicity, I ignored that parameter. Here we can try for any other parameter that is present in the code itself, for example, the parameter `m`.
[image: Graph]

Comment: There are several similar questions posted by you. Instead of giving feedback you prefer to post new questions, no good style!

Comment: I am not getting the desired answer. That's why I am posting. If you are unable to help then please ignore. Thank you.

Comment: If you "don't get the desired answer" you should give a feedback. This interaction makes stackexchange work and honors the effort made by users trying to help you!

Comment: O.K. Thank you.

Comment: How is parameter `\[Beta]` defined?

Comment: here `beta1` is another parameter involved in the problem. But for simplicity, I ignored that parameter. Here we can try for any other parameter that is present in the code itself, for example, the parameter `m`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definitions (keep h undefined)

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
a = 0.5;
b = 2.0;
t = 0.0;
Q0 = 1.0;
alp = 0.5;
alpha = 0.5;
beta = 1.0;
k = 0.5;
m = 10.0;

eq1 = {s''[y] == (m/alpha)*Sinh[alpha*s[y]]};
bc1 = {s'[0] == 0, s[h] == 1};
eq2 = {p''''[y] - (1/k)*p''[y] + beta*m*m*s'[y] == 0};
bc2 = {p[0] == 0, p''[0] == 0, p[h] == F, p'[h] == 0};
```

function `ph[...]` returns `p'''[y] - (1/k)*p'[y] + (beta*m*m*s[y])`

```
ph[h_, F_] :=Block[{sol}, 
sol = NDSolveValue[{s''[y] == (m/alpha)*Sinh[alpha*s[y]],p''''[y] - (1/k)*p''[y] + beta*m*m*s'[y] == 0, 
s'[0] == 0,s[h] == 1, p[0] == 0, p''[0] == 0, p[h] == F, p'[h] == 0}, 
p'''[y] - (1/k)*p'[y] + (beta*m*m*s[y]), {y, 0, 1} ]    
]
```

integration

```
xi = Range[0, 1, .02];
hi = Map[1.0 - (a*Cos[Pi*(# - t)]*Cos[Pi*(# - t)]) &, xi];
data = MapThread[{#1, NIntegrate[ph[#2, 1], {y, 0, 1}]} &, {xi, hi}];
ListPlot[data]
```

[image]

**addendum( modified with new function `ph0[]` )**

```
ph0[h_, F_] := 
Block[{sol}, 
sol = NDSolveValue[{s''[y] == (m/alpha)*Sinh[alpha*s[y]],p''''[y] - (1/k)*p''[y] + beta*m*m*s'[y] == 0, s'[0] == 0,s[h] == 1, p[0] == 0, p''[0] == 0, p[h] == F, p'[h] == 0}, 
p'''[0] - (1/k)*p'[0] + (beta*m*m*s[0]), {y, 0, 1}]]


Fi = Range[-3, 3];
Fdp=Map[{#, NIntegrate[ph0[1.0 - (a*Cos[Pi*(x - t)]*Cos[Pi*(x - t)]), #],{x, 0,1}]} &, Fi    ]//Quiet
ListPlot[{Fdp, Fdp}, AxesLabel -> {F, dp}, Joined -> {True, False}]
```

[image]

Comment: It seems to be fine. But here you have considered the range of the dependent variable `y` as `[0,1]`. Also as I mentioned in my question I want to plot integration of `(p'''[0] - ((1.0/k)*p''[0]) + (beta*m*m*s[0])` with respect to the variable `x` vs the parameter `F`. However, the desired graph should look different. I have edited the question. Please see.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the required result. But when I try to run it in my system the code is running for 3-4 hours with lots of errors and I don't get any output.

Comment: See my modified answer. Sorry, don't know we it evaluated yesterday

Comment: Thank you. Now it is working fine. However, I've two questions for my understanding. 1. Why do you consider the range of y, [0,1] instead of [0,h]? 2. What is the reason for writing `{Fdp,Fdp}` twice in `ListPlot[{Fdp, Fdp}, AxesLabel -> {F, dp}, Joined -> {True, False}]`?

Comment: Also, is it possible to plot the variation for four different values of the variable `m` say `m=5, 10, 15, 20` in the same figure?

Comment: I took the integration rang `[0,1]` to avoid problems for the case `h->0`. For the solution of the boundaryvalueproblem it shouldn't matter. In `ListPlot`I took `Fdp twice to make a line and point plot (see option `Joined->...`

Comment: You could add an additional parameter `m` in the definitions of `ph[...],ph0[...]`

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much for your help and time.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148557/discussion-between-dr-b-mallick-and-ulrich-neumann).

Comment: Could you please spend some more time on this to fix one more issue? I am now trying to get the result for two different values of `m`. As per your direction, I make some changes like `ph[h_, F_, m_] := ...` and `ph0[h_, F_, m_] := ...` and `ListPlot[{Fdp, Fdp}, {m, {5, 10}}, AxesLabel -> {F, dp}, Joined -> {True, False}]`. But I am not getting the result. Could you please suggest what to do?

Comment: For every m-value create a plot `plot1=ListPlot[{Fdp, Fdp},...` ( plot1,plot2,...) and combine the plots with `Show[{plot1,plot2,...}]`

Comment: Thank you for your response. But in that case it shows a error `Could not combine the graphics objects in Show` instead of giving required result.

Comment: Could you please help me to fix the issue that I have mentioned?

Comment: Hard to give an answer without code! If you evaluate the different plots `plot1,...` does the intended plot show?